# Why does golang time function fail on certain dates

Tags: go

I have checked the other suggestions for fixing this problem and they don't work.

The current code seems to work until you enter a different date and then I get random failures like below.

The code is as follows:

```
yy, mm, dd = 11, 27, 2019
s_yy, s_mm, s_dd = 11, 1, 2019
e_yy, e_mm, e_dd = 1, 1, 2020

input := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d-%d", yy, mm, dd)
input += "T15:04:05.000-07:00"
t, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", input)

input_s := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d-%d", s_yy, s_mm, s_dd)
input_s += "T15:04:05.000-07:00"
t_s, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", input_s)

input_e := fmt.Sprintf("%d-%d-%d", e_yy, e_mm, e_dd)
input_e += "T15:04:05.000-07:00"
t_e, _ := time.Parse("2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00", input_e)

fmt.Println("t = ", t, "  t_s = ", t_s, "  t_e", t_e)
```

The result is the following:

t =  2019-12-27 15:04:05 -0700 -0700   t_s =  0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC   t_e 0001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 UTC

Any Help would be a help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: None of those are valid dates, you are attempting to parse `11-27-2019T15:04:05.000-07:00`, `11-1-2019T15:04:05.000-07:00`, and `1-1-2020T15:04:05.000-07:00` as `YYYY-MM-DD` when they are `M-D-YYYY`. Don't ignore the errors from `time.Parse`, they show you what's wrong. Make sure they are in the right order and your months/days have the leading `0` (using `%02d` in the `Sprintf` format string)

Answer (score 1):

You got problems in your code.

1. The order of your variable is wrong.
   `yy, mm, dd = 11, 27, 2019` should be `yy, mm, dd = 2019, 11, 27`.
2. Don't ignore the error. If you got problem, just print it will be a lot of help (or better is writing a test)
3. Your format is wrong. It should in form like `fmt.Sprintf("%d-%02d-%02d", yy, mm, dd)`

You can check the result [here](https://play.golang.org/p/Ydl_UqTHs_o)

Comment: Thanks the format string was the fix.  I specified the inputs wropng (My BAD)